# Error while creating Database view in ABAP

Tags: sql-view, sap-data-dictionary

I am trying to create a database view in ABAP Dictionary.

I have given the join condition for tables  table_a and table_b  as
table_a-data = table_b-data.

I have mentioned all the primary key fields in the view fields tab and I have mentioned where conditions where Mandt = '602' and facing the following errors

1. > selection condition is not permitted for client
2. > field table_a-data does not belong to base table.

I have tried to modify the comparison value but didn't work.
also switched the tables order to eliminate the error with base table but didn't work.

Comment: The client condition has to be removed, it is handled automatically in SAP/ABAP

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hardcode the client value in selection conditions.

Follow the below steps for proper handling of client in database view

- In Table/Join conditions, use `table_a-mandt = table_b-mandt` (so that data from cross clients is not used in join condition)
- Have `MANDT` as the first field in View Fields (so that compiler can pass current client as default value during data selection).

If you want access to cross-client data, you can achieve the same using `CLIENT SPECIFIED` or `USING CLIENT` key words as below.

```
SELECT * from DataBaseView USING CLIENT '062' into table @data(lt).

SELECT * from DataBaseView CLIENT SPECIFIED where mandt = '062' into table @data(lt).
```